# Как поменять очередность Actor в Stage?

Tags: android, libgdx

можно ли у Stage настроить очередность вывода Actor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок вывода зависит от zIndex'а ( Индекса глубины ). Задается через [Actor.setZIndex(int)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setZIndex-int-)